# How to send lightning payment request to lnurl from Android app with extra comment data?

Tags: lightning-network, payment, android, invoices

I'm looking for a way to include extra description (comment) info in a lightning payment request i.e. [LUD-12](https://github.com/lnurl/luds/blob/luds/12.md).

Either with anchor link:

```
<a href="lightning:bitanon@getalby.com" comment="payer@email.com">send ln payment</a>
```

Or even better using an Android Intent:

```
Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND).apply {

    data = Uri.parse("lightning:bitanon@getalby.com") 
    //type = "message/rfc822"
    putExtra("comment", "payer@email.com")

}
```

The above anchor link works, but does not send comment data to receiving wallet. And I can't get the Android intent to launch wallet app at all. Anyone know how to get this working?

Comment: Tried "lightning:bitanon@getalby.com?comment=foo"?

Comment: Yeah, doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

The fine folks at [Alby](https://getalby.com/) helped solve this ->

**First**, add query intent to manifest:

```
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data android:scheme="lightning" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

**Second**, query getalby.com for encoded *lnurl*:

```
val requestUrl = "https://getalby.com/lnurlp/bitanon/callback?amount=1000000&comment=hello" // amount is in millisats
val client = OkHttpClient() 
val request = Request.Builder().url(requestUrl).build() 
val response = client.newCall(request).await()
```

**Third**, parse json response for 'pr' which contains encoded *lnurl*.

**Fourth**, send Lightning PayRequest Android Intent, which will open with device lightning wallet of your choice:

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).apply {
    data = Uri.parse("lightning:$lnurl")
}
if (intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

**Fifth**, parse and handle additional response info, such as transaction verification url etc.